# How do E-Scooters Scanning Flow Works?

Tags: api, mobile, architecture, qr-code, software-design

I'm trying to connect a device to an E-Scooter (like Bird for example).
 I want this device, to be able to make a beep sound when the specific scooter has been scanned. I was wondering,
 what is the flow that happens in the software?

here's an example:

**Step 1**: User(who's logged in and entered credit card) scans QR code. 
**Step 2**: The Bird app sends some API call to their servers with the Scooter ID / Serial number. 
**Step 3:** The server authenticates the request, and send a response to the User's mobile device. 
**Step 4:** Scooter unlocks and ready to ride.

How does the scooter, which I guess has no internet connection (?), knows when to unlock itself? 
Does Bluetooth play a role here?

Comment: The scooter is connected to the bird servers (or is addressable by them) all the time. So on Step3 the notification is sent to it to unlock.

Answer (score 1):

The scooter *does* have a modem. According to [this article about their security](https://hackaday.com/2019/02/12/security-engineering-inside-the-scooter-startups/), it is the [Quectel EC21-V](https://www.everythingrf.com/products/cellular-modules/quectel/811-439-ec21-v) which is capable of 2G, 3G, and 4G.

These modems are very efficient, they don't need much power and only have to send / receive a few bytes.

So, the Bird servers either send data or an SMS to the bike, which tells it to unlock.